# Vue - Component won't re-render when updating data with a method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, methods, components, render

I have a very simple vue components that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="incrementor">
    <p v-text="counter"></p>
    <button v-on:click="increment()">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="../scripts/incrementor.ts"></script>
<style lang="scss" src="../styles/incrementor.scss"></style>
```

This is my 'incrementor.ts' script file:

```
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class Incrementor extends Vue {
  private counter: number = 0;

  increment = () => {
    this.counter++;
  };
}
```

My problem is that when i click the button i can see the counter increasing in the console but the component doesn't re-render so the 'counter' text in the browser stays at 0.

I know i can do it like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="incrementor">
    <p v-text="counter"></p>
    <button v-on:click="counter++">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="../scripts/incrementor.ts"></script>
<style lang="scss" src="../styles/incrementor.scss"></style>
```

And it works but i want to be able to use my own methods for this.

Comment: Just remove `()` from function call and use it like: `v-on:click="increment"`

Comment: still same result

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-class-component-example-7154b?file=/components/Hello.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues here:

1. Instead of calling the function directly, we need to pass the function reference like:

   ```
    <button v-on:click="increment">
   ```
2. Next, as mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components), component methods can be declared as instance methods like:

   ```
    increment() {
       this.counter++;
    };
   ```

After implementing these changes, the increment counter will work fine.

[image: Edit vue-class-component-example-k6bc4]

Comment: It works now, it was the arrow function that messed it up i think. Thanks.